# Taking the selected value CardNumber a combo box on form1 to form2

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to get the selected card number that has logged in via entering their pin number from an sql database which I then need to match that selected card number to retrieve their balance from the database and display it into a rich text box. I have been able to take the PIN from the database and match it with the users cardnumber to give them access to form 2 but i am finding it difficult to take the selected card number from the combo box on form1 and use it to retrieve the selected users balance once i click on the balance button and display it on form2 richtextbox. I have the following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public int logAttempts = 3;
    public string accountNo;      

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void BtnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int index = cBCardNumber.SelectedIndex;

        DataRow dpin = dataSet1ATMCards.Tables["ATMCards"].Rows[index];
        String pin = dpin.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();           

        if (textBoxPin.Text.Length == 4)
        {
            if (String.Equals(pin, textBoxPin.Text))
            {
                Form2 frm2;
                frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.ShowDialog();
            }
            else
            {
                if (loginAttempts == 1)
                {

                    sqlCommandConfiscated.Parameters["@cardNumber"].Value = cBCardNumber.Text;
                    sqlCommandConfiscated.Parameters["@confiscated"].Value = true;

                    try
                    {
                        sqlCommandConfiscated.Connection.Open();
                        sqlCommandConfiscated.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        MessageBox.Show("You have reached your maximum login attempts.");
                        textBoxPin.Clear();

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        sqlCommandConfiscated.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    loginAttempts--;
                    MessageBox.Show("You have entered the Wrong Pin. You have " + loginAttempts);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your 4 digit Pin Number");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        sqlDataAdapter1.Fill(dataSet1ATMCards.ATMCards);       

    }

    private void cBCardNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loginAttempts = 3;
    }   

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a PIN property to fm2

and do

```
Form2 frm2;                 
frm2 = new Form2(); 
frm2.PIN =  pin;               
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

and then is one way.

Basic trick is to make fm2 independant of fm1. You could overload ShowDialog and pass it in there as well.
Have some sort of common struct / class and use it from both.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create a structure with PIN as its member, set its value in form1 and use it in form2.

*Structure:*

```
public struct Person
{
    public string PIN { get; set; }
}
```

*Form1:*

```
        Person p = new Person();
        p.PIN = dpin.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();
        Form2 frmPopup = new Form2();
        frmPopup.p = p;
        frmPopup.ShowDialog();
```

*Form2:*

```
        public Person p { get; set; }
```